# Is the uWSGI master process useful on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, uwsgi

My understanding is that the master process is for coordinating rolling restarts and such. This isn't relevant on Heroku. However, the heroku guide in the documentation includes it in the config, with no explanation:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/heroku_python.html#creating-the-uwsgi-config-file

Why would it be useful on Heroku?

Comment: Why do you think that it isn't relevant on Heroku?

Comment: because "My understanding is that the master process is for coordinating rolling restarts and such", which aren't relevant on Heroku.

Comment: I understand that part, but what about that: "aren't relevant on Heroku"? Does heroku restart your app gracefuly by itself? Or you think that there won't be need for that?

Comment: One does not typically keep a process running in a heroku dyno and then send it signals. If a daemon needs to be restarted on heroku, the entire dyno is taken down and a new one is brought up.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, the master isn't used to control rolling restarts, it's for the  `memory-report` option that the configuration recommends you use. With `uWSGI`, the master also controls advanced `logging` and `statistics`.